# Не могу поменять размер шрифта при экспорте отчета ireport в excel

Tags: java

Использую ireport 5.6.0.

Создал отчет. Например, в заголовке размер шрифта ставлю 12.
При просмотре все нормально, но при экспорте в программе почему-то используется шрифт по умолчанию ко всему документу:

```
String spec = this.getAsString("DOLG");
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", Boolean.TRUE);  

JasperReport mainReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(spec);
JRProperties.setProperty(JRTextElement.PROPERTY_PRINT_KEEP_FULL_TEXT, true);
JRBeanCollectionDataSource mainBeans = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(collection);  
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(mainReport, map, mainBeans);
// jasperPrint.getDefaultStyle().getFontSize();
JRXlsExporter xlse = new JRXlsExporter();
xlse.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
xlse.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, new File(getAsString("RESULT_FILE")));
xlse.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER, Boolean.FALSE);
xlse.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
xlse.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.FALSE);
xlse.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IMAGE_BORDER_FIX_ENABLED, Boolean.FALSE);
xlse.exportReport();
```

В чем может быть дело?